# How to substitute oracle pl/sql variable in where clause of select

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, bind-variables

Inside the function ,

I am having the following function,

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION DiffMaxMinPrice
 return double precision
is 
 diffprice double precision := 0;
 minprice long; 
 maxprice long;
 value long;
 indexid number(19,0);
begin

for row in 
 (SELECT  x.* into minprice , maxprice 
       FROM sampletable ,
            XMLTABLE ('//book'
                      PASSING sampletable.xmlcol
                      COLUMNS maxprice VARCHAR2(30) PATH '@maxprice',
                              minprice VARCHAR2(30) PATH '@minprice') x 
                              where sampletable.indexid = 2)
 LOOP
  ....
 END LOOP;


 return 1;
end;
```

Instead of hard coding with 2, i would like to substiute the variable idxid. I keep getting invalid number when I substituted a variable there.

`indexid :=2` 
And the where part of the select statement as

`sampletable.indexid = indexid`

Answer (score 0):

You can make it as a cursor with a parameter, like this:

```
cursor cs ( pIndexId IN number ) is 
(SELECT  x.* into minprice , maxprice 
           FROM sampletable ,
                XMLTABLE ('//book'
                          PASSING sampletable.xmlcol
                          COLUMNS maxprice VARCHAR2(30) PATH '@maxprice',
                                  minprice VARCHAR2(30) PATH '@minprice') x 
                                  where sampletable.indexid = pIndexId );

csrom cs%rowtype;
```

And then you use it as:

```
open cs( someVariableYouNeed );
loop
    fetch cs into csrom
    exit when cs%NOT_FOUND;

    --do whatever you need here

end loop;
close cs;
```

If you have this variable in your code you can also use it on your code. It will work fine.

```
for row in 
  (SELECT  x.* into minprice , maxprice 
       FROM sampletable ,
            XMLTABLE ('//book'
                      PASSING sampletable.xmlcol
                      COLUMNS maxprice VARCHAR2(30) PATH '@maxprice',
                              minprice VARCHAR2(30) PATH '@minprice') x 
                              where sampletable.indexid = someVariableYouNeed )
```

If you are getting: **Invalid number** that means that either the column is not of type number or your variable has a value that is not a number.

Comment: I want to substitute a variable for that indexid. The value of indexid is from another query.

Comment: Thats is just an example. You can use instead of `1` what ever variable you want. I will edit it.

Comment: It is not working even if I give assign it before like  this, 
`indexid := 2;` and then use it

Comment: What is the type of `sampletable.indexid` column? If you are getting this error it means that this column is not a number or has a value that cannot be implicit converted to a number.

Comment: how is the types of minprice , maxprice defined? of `into minprice , maxprice`

Comment: Yes they are all defined . It is working fine when I give as sampletable.indexid = 2; (Or any number) .

Comment: So I'm guessing that you have this code inside a loop and when you use a variable to bind that value, at some point you are having this error, is that it?

Comment: If I hard code the values it is working, but when I substitute some variables it is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57369/discussion-between-nishanth-lawrence-and-jorge-campos).